# struts2 forcefully redirecting https url to http

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jsp, ssl, struts2

I have written an application in struts2, deployed in aws instance and configured ssl. In some of the action classes mapping i have written redirection in the below approach.

```
    <action name="autocomplete" class="configuration.routers.autocomplete.AutoCompleteAction">
        <result name="showadd">/configuration/routers/autocomplete/Add.jsp</result>            
        <result name="showedit">/configuration/routers/autocomplete/Edit.jsp</result>
        <result name="success" type="tiles">AutoComplteConfigDisplay</result>
        <result name="display" type="redirect">autocomplete.action</result>
        <result name="failure" type="tiles">failurepage</result>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">failurepage</result>
    </action>
```

whenever i am trying to add any record and redirecting to listing page i am getting forcefully redirected to http://..... url.

In result the request is getting blocked by chrome. below is the sample error.

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://..../validateuser.action?mode=login was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure form action 'http://.../sampleaction.do?mode=display'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

can some one help how i can redirect https://... request to https://.... url in struts2.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [AWS load balancer set up](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/) issue.

Ensure you do configure "redirect" under the Rule Action type to translate http to https.